# getting filtered rows array from vue-tables-2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js, vue-tables-2

I need some help with a popular vue libraries https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2.

I have a filter fixed for the rows but now I need the filtered rows(the objects of rows) stored in an array does anyone know how to achieve this?

I hope this is integrated in the libraries itself because I don't like to fix a hacky solution.

I tried to look it up in the documentation but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

> You can use the `allFilteredData` property of the component.

Longer answer using working examples:

You can use a `ref` on an instance of the table component and then access the `allFilteredData` property.

Here are two examples:

The code below in available in a full fiddle. Typing "zi" into the filter for example and clcking the "Process Filtered Result" button under the table. Clicking the button results in a method accessing the `allFilteredData` property.

https://jsfiddle.net/tzdw17qo/

Given this partial code from that fiddle example:

```
  <v-client-table ref="countries" :columns="columns" v-model="data" :options="options">...</v-client-table>
  <button @click="handleFilteredResult">Process Filtered Result</button>
  <textarea ref="json_dump"></textarea>
```

A method such as this will have the reference to the filtered data to do something more useful with. This is just a basic working example:

```
    methods: {
     /**
      * Log out allFilteredData for now for demo only 
      * @TODO Something specific with the data
      */
     handleFilteredResult () {
      // log the value of the allFilteredData attribute
      console.log({allFilteredData: this.$refs.countries.allFilteredData});
       // for example write the json version out to a textarea:
       this.$refs.json_dump.value = JSON.stringify(this.$refs.countries.allFilteredData);
     }
    },
```

Then another example where listening to the "filter" event:

https://jsfiddle.net/ev645umy/

Html from the fiddle:

```
  <!-- bind to the `filter` event of the component -->
  <v-client-table ref="countries" @filter="onFilter" :columns="columns" v-model="gridData" :options="options">
```

JavaScript from the fiddle:

```
  methods: {
   /**
    * Log out allFilteredData for now for demo only 
    * @TODO Something specific with the data
    */
   onFilter () {
   // as of this writing, the `filter` event fires before the data is filtered so we wait to access the filtered data
   setTimeout(() => {
    console.log({allFilteredData: this.$refs.countries.allFilteredData});
    this.$refs.json_dump.value = JSON.stringify(this.$refs.countries.allFilteredData);
   }, 250);
  }
  },
```

More info:

- https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/properties
- https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/events

Comment: Thanks! Is this also posible without a button.  For example :in a lifecycle or an event from vue-tables?

Comment: @tester, yes vue-tables-2 has a "filter" event that you can bind to for another example. See https://jsfiddle.net/ev645umy/